# Google Sheets query function based on multiple rows and/or columns

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

[Data Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl7CS.png)

Please assist a newbie with a query about query where 1 = Total Gross or Employers Cost based on the department and pay period.

So from the Data Sheet to a query on another sheet, I would be able to select February and Data it would produce Column C, D, I & J

Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you actaully tried? This looks quite straight forward...? Also post what you are expecting to be the output based on your parameters.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1):

**Use this formula**

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:J, "Select A, C, D, I, J Where A = '"&$B$3&"' ", 1)
```

[image]

### Demo

[image]